# how can i unzip a zip file with creating a new folder on the given path in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, zip, unzip

i have to unzip a file, i don't want to CD and then run mkdir newfolder then come again to the folder where i have the zip file and then run unzip file.zip /home/user/newfolder

i want to simply run the command from the whichever directory i am it will create the folder for me or ask me that on location /home/user there's no newfolder directory exist do you want to create one (Y/n)? and chose it to y
(doesn't matter if this operation need root access)

i have checked unzip swtiches and google but in all the exmaples they make a directory then unzip the file in it

i am using Debian Buster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man unzip` says:

```
 unzip [-Z] [-cflptTuvz[abjnoqsCDKLMUVWX$/:^]] file[.zip] [file(s) ...]  [-x xfile(s) ...] [-d exdir]
```

> [-d exdir]
>                 An optional directory to which to extract files.  By default, all files and subdirectories are recreated in  the  current  directory;  the  -d
>                 option  allows  extraction  in  an  arbitrary  directory (always assuming one has permission to write to the directory).  This option need not
>                 appear at the end of the command line; it is also accepted before the zipfile specification (with the normal options), immediately  after  the
>                 zipfile specification, or between the file(s) and the -x option.  The option and directory may be concatenated without any white space between
>                 them, but note that this may cause normal shell behavior to be suppressed.  In particular, `-d ~` (tilde) is expanded by Unix C shells  into
>                 the name of the user's home directory, but `-d~` is treated as a literal subdirectory `~` of the current directory.

Alternatively, 7zip (`7z` command) supports the ZIP format and has a `-o` parameter for the same purpose

Answer (score 2):

The `-d` in situation (fish shell), where the folder name is derived from the archive name:

```
for i in *.zip ; unzip $i -d (basename $i .zip) ; end
```

Only issue, when the archive already embeds a folder, you end up with a superfluous level.

Hence, I want to mention that `unar` does the right thing (tm): automatically creates a folder, but only when the root of the archive isn't one.
This behavior can be overriden with the same `-d` option.
Plus, `unar` handles zip, rar, etc...

What's not to love?